# Area Plot with Gradient using MatPlotLib

Tags: python, matplotlib, gradient, stock

I have coded the following script that makes Area plot with gradient for Exxon and Walmart.

The plot has gradient that goes from left to right, instead I'd like the gradient to be darkest at the highest close value, and lightest at the bottom of every bar.

The CSV data files are at URLs
..(1) http://salilgangal.com/info/XOM.csv
..(2) http://salilgangal.com/info/WMT.csv

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.path import Path
from matplotlib.patches import PathPatch
import pandas as pd

def create_area_plot(xx, yy, gradient_cmap, filename, title, y_offset):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    
    # Create a closed path from the data
    path_data = np.column_stack((xx, yy))
    path_data = np.vstack([path_data, [xx[-1], y_offset], [xx[0], y_offset]])  # Close the path
    path = Path(path_data)
    patch = PathPatch(path, facecolor='none')
    ax.add_patch(patch)

    # Calculate the gradient color values
    color_values = np.linspace(0, 1, len(xx))
    
    # Create a smooth gradient-filled area chart
    for i in range(len(xx) - 1):
        ax.fill_between(xx[i:i+2], [yy[i], yy[i]], [y_offset, y_offset], color=gradient_cmap(color_values[i]))

    # Customize the plot
    ax.set_xlabel('Date')
    ax.set_ylabel('Close')
    ax.set_title(title)
    
    # Format the X-axis labels as 'mm/dd/yyyy'
    ax.set_xticks(xx[::len(xx)//10])  # Adjust the number of ticks for better readability
    ax.set_xticklabels([x.strftime('%m/%d/%Y') for x in pd.to_datetime(xom_dates[::len(xx)//10])], rotation=45, ha="right")
    
    plt.savefig(filename)
    plt.show()
    plt.close()

xom_data = pd.read_csv('XOM.csv')
wmt_data = pd.read_csv('WMT.csv')

xom_data['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(xom_data['Date'])
wmt_data['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(wmt_data['Date'])

xom_dates = xom_data['Date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
wmt_dates = wmt_data['Date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
xom_close_prices = xom_data['Close']
wmt_close_prices = wmt_data['Close']

xx = np.arange(0, xom_dates.size, 1)

yy_xom = xom_close_prices.values
yy_wmt = wmt_close_prices.values

# Define the Y-axis offset as 5% lower than the lowest Close value for each stock
y_offset_xom = min(yy_xom) - 0.05 * (max(yy_xom) - min(yy_xom))
y_offset_wmt = min(yy_wmt) - 0.05 * (max(yy_wmt) - min(yy_wmt))

create_area_plot(xx, yy_xom, plt.cm.Blues, "xom_area_chart.png", "XOM Stock Prices", y_offset_xom)
create_area_plot(xx, yy_wmt, plt.cm.Reds, "wmt_area_chart.png", "WMT Stock Prices", y_offset_wmt)
```

[image]

[image]

Details are given in the code

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see, this requires a "hand rolled" solution and there is no clean or neat way. From the top of my head I see three options

1. create an array with your data (i.e., how the histogram would **look** like) and use `imshow`. There you can specify the color values as values of the array.
2. Use `matplotlib.patches.Rectangle` to create rectangles of different colors and stack them vertically to re-reate the image.
3. Use a multi-colored line (`colorline`), where each line is a single bar (you still need to calculate the color at the end of the bar): https://nbviewer.org/github/dpsanders/matplotlib-examples/blob/master/colorline.ipynb

None of these possibilities are really great, but they would do the job (somehow) ...

Comment: In English:
Presently each "bar" plotted for every "date" has "height/width" as the physical dimension, and presently each "bar" has a unique/uniform color.  What's necessary for the gradient plotting is that each bar ought to retain height/width as is, but ought to have darker color at top and lighter color at the bottom.  (In Python:  I am looking for help from this forum about how to do what I indicated in English to Python.)